# Changing the JFrame title

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

This code compiles, I just can't get the name to change on the title bar.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import javax.swing.JButton;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;  
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;  
import javax.swing.JTextArea;  
import javax.swing.JTextField;  
public class VolumeCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
{  
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;  
    private JPanel options;  
    JTextField poolLengthText, poolWidthText, poolDepthText, poolVolumeText, hotTub,  
            hotTubLengthText, hotTubWidthText, hotTubDepthText, hotTubVolumeText, temp, results,
            myTitle;  
    JTextArea labelTubStatus;  
    public VolumeCalculator()  
    {  
        setSize(400, 250);  
        setVisible(true);  
        setSize(400, 250);  
        setVisible(true);  
        setTitle("Volume Calculator");  
        setSize(300, 200);  
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();  
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);  

        createOptions();  

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();  

        jtabbedPane.addTab("Options", options);  

        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    } 
    /* CREATE OPTIONS */ 

    public void createOptions()  
    {  
        options = new JPanel();  
        options.setLayout(null);  
        JLabel labelOptions = new JLabel("Change Company Name:");  
        labelOptions.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);  
        options.add(labelOptions);  
        JTextField newTitle = new JTextField("Some Title"); 
        newTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);  
        options.add(newTitle);
        myTitle = new JTextField();   
        myTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20); 
        myTitle.add(labelOptions); 
        JButton newName = new JButton("Set New Name");  
        newName.setBounds(60, 80, 150, 20);  
        newName.addActionListener(this);  
        options.add(newName);  
        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");  
        Exit.setBounds(250, 80, 80, 20);  
        Exit.addActionListener(this);  
        options.add(Exit);  
    }  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)  
    {  
        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();  
        String buttonLabel = button.getText();  
        if ("Exit".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel))  
        {  
            Exit_pressed();  
            return;  
        }  
        if ("Set New Name".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel))  
        {  
            New_Name();  
            return;  
        }  
    }  
    private void Exit_pressed()  
    {  
        System.exit(0);  
    }  
    private void New_Name()  
    {  
        this.setTitle(myTitle.getText());  
    }  
    private void Options()  
    {  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        JFrame frame = new VolumeCalculator();  
        frame.setSize(380, 350);  
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: setTitle() must be called from an object instance, not from static JFrame. Be careful when naming an object instance to avoid the confusion with a class name.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your class extends JFrame then use `this.setTitle(newTitle.getText());`

If not and it contains a JFrame let's say named myFrame, then use `myFrame.setTitle(newTitle.getText());`

Now that you have posted your program, it is obvious that you need only one JTextField to get the new title. These changes will do the trick:

```
JTextField poolLengthText, poolWidthText, poolDepthText, poolVolumeText, hotTub,
        hotTubLengthText, hotTubWidthText, hotTubDepthText, hotTubVolumeText, temp, results,
        newTitle;
```

and:

```
    public void createOptions()
    {
        options = new JPanel();
        options.setLayout(null);
        JLabel labelOptions = new JLabel("Change Company Name:");
        labelOptions.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        options.add(labelOptions);
        newTitle = new JTextField("Some Title");
        newTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);
        options.add(newTitle);
//        myTitle = new JTextField("My Title...");
//        myTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);
//        myTitle.add(labelOptions);
        JButton newName = new JButton("Set New Name");
        newName.setBounds(60, 80, 150, 20);
        newName.addActionListener(this);
        options.add(newName);
        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        Exit.setBounds(250, 80, 80, 20);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        options.add(Exit);
    }
```

and:

```
private void New_Name()
{
    this.setTitle(newTitle.getText());
}
```

Comment: @Costis:  It does extend JFrame.  I tried what you said, but get the same error.

Comment: Try to add some text to your newTitle JTextField: newTitle.setText("title");

Comment: @Costis:  I tried this.setTitle(newTitle.getText("Title"));  No luck

Comment: Change this line JTextField newTitle = new JTextField(); to   JTextField newTitle = new JTextField("Some Title"); If it does not work post your entire code.

Comment: @Costis:  The code above now compiles to show what it is not doing.

Comment: Everything is fine, but... you set the empty field myTitle as a JFrame Title. If you substitute the contents of the brackets in this line:  myTitle = new JTextField("My Title..."); (around line 60) it will react.

Comment: @Costis:  Are you talking about replacing that line word for word?  I did that and it just changed the title to "My Title"

Comment: Yes, the problem was because myTitle is always null. See the three changes above. I deleted myTitle and use newTitle for getting the title text.

Answer (score 6):

`newTitle` is a local variable where you create the fields. So when that functions ends, the variable `newTitle`, does not exist anymore. (The JTextField that was referenced by `newTitle` does still exist however.)

Thus, increase the scope of the variable, so that you can access it another method.

```
public SomeFrame extends JFrame {
   JTextField myTitle;//can be used anywhere in this class

   creationOfTheFields()
   {
   //other code
      myTitle = new JTextField("spam");  
      myTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);
      options.add(myTitle);
   //blabla other code
   }

   private void New_Name()  
   {  
      this.setTitle(myTitle.getText());  
   } 
}
```

Comment: @lshtar: Getting close, when I type in a new name and click "Set New Name" the title disappears.  I'm not sure if I have something in the wrong place or what.

Comment: @lshtar: Now if I click the "Set New Name" button the title changes to "spam".  I can't change it.  After I close it and re-open it the tile is set back.

Answer (score 2):

these methods can help
setTitle("your new title");
or 
super("your new title");

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help Mike with his issue?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you learn how to use layout managers to get the layout you want to see.  `null` layouts are fragile, and cause no end of trouble.

Try this source & check the comments.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class VolumeCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
    private JPanel options;
    JTextField poolLengthText, poolWidthText, poolDepthText, poolVolumeText, hotTub,
            hotTubLengthText, hotTubWidthText, hotTubDepthText, hotTubVolumeText, temp, results,
            myTitle;
    JTextArea labelTubStatus;

    public VolumeCalculator(){
        setSize(400, 250);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 250);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Volume Calculator");
        setSize(300, 200);
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        createOptions();

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        jtabbedPane.addTab("Options", options);

        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    /* CREATE OPTIONS */

    public void createOptions(){
        options = new JPanel();
        //options.setLayout(null);
        JLabel labelOptions = new JLabel("Change Company Name:");
        labelOptions.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        options.add(labelOptions);
        JTextField newTitle = new JTextField("Some Title");
        //newTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);    
        options.add(newTitle);
        myTitle = new JTextField(20);
        // myTitle WAS NEVER ADDED to the GUI!
        options.add(myTitle);
        //myTitle.setBounds(80, 40, 225, 20);
        //myTitle.add(labelOptions);
        JButton newName = new JButton("Set New Name");
        //newName.setBounds(60, 80, 150, 20);
        newName.addActionListener(this);
        options.add(newName);
        JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
        //Exit.setBounds(250, 80, 80, 20);
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        options.add(Exit);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
        String buttonLabel = button.getText();
        if ("Exit".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
            Exit_pressed();
            return;
        }
        if ("Set New Name".equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLabel)){
            New_Name();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void Exit_pressed(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void New_Name(){
        System.out.println("'" + myTitle.getText() + "'");
        this.setTitle(myTitle.getText());
    }

    private void Options(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new VolumeCalculator();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(380, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```