# How to create a JFrame with a title

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do you create a JFrame with a title using Java Eclipse? I've tried using 
    package frame;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setText("abc");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the JFrame title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487615/changing-the-jframe-title)

Comment: Always remember, functions/methods are almost always named after what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use .setTitle(); to set the title.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps using the `setTitle` method

```
frame.setTitle("abc");
```

or alternatively

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("abc");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to create a `JFrame` with title:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
```

This is the way to create a `JFrame` and set its title:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Title");
```

And this is the [first result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) of Google for ***create jframe with title***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.awt.*;

public class MyFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("abc");
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```