# get user input assign it to String

Tags: java

Is it possible to assign user-input to a string? So the same way as you would assign it to a double:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter here the value of x: ");
double x = s.nextDouble();
```

And is it possible to make a JFrame, and name the JFrame to a String, so in Eclipse if you would ask for the title for your JFrame, that you can enter it into the console, and the JFrame name would change(or do you have to update the frame, if so, how?)

I am a beginner so please keep it as simple as possible(I am also from The Netherlands so sorry for bad Englisch).

Comment: There are many tutorials online, so try some and if you have any problems feel free to ask them! But at least try something before you ask it here...

Comment: ok, sorry. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: to make this quick... yes, but not like that, there should be multiple answers here on SO, that demonstrate how. No, no, and what you want to do is wrong on so many levels....

Comment: I know that's why i ask

Comment: Take a look at: [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [Changing the JFrame title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487615/changing-the-jframe-title)

Answer (score 2):

Just read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) of the `Scanner` class. They state that there are 3 methods that return `String`s from the user input:

```
next(): String
next(Pattern pattern): String
next(String pattern): String
nextLine(): String
```

Comment: ok thx, I'll go check it out